# Remote_Addr doesn't work after apache upgrade

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, nginx, ip

I just upgraded from apache2.2 to apache2.4, suddly Remote_Addr prints 127.1.1.0 instead of client ip. I have apache behaind nginx with the following settings:

```
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_connect_timeout 60;
                proxy_send_timeout 60;
                proxy_read_timeout 60;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've read your question correctly you have:

```
 internet -> nginx -> apache
```

If you want the Apache PHP/access.log/CGI environments to show the requesting (external) IP then you want to use `mod_rpaf`.

NOTE:  If you've upgraded `mod_rpaf` recently you might find it doesn't work, due to this bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libapache2-mod-rpaf/+bug/1126233

Comment: it always worked without this module prior to upgrade ...

Comment: Are you sure?  nginx will set the headers, but Apache won't know about them.  If you have magic-code that checks the headers I could believe it, but most code just uses ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'} and apache won't update that without mod_rpaf, or mod_headers.

Comment: now we have an internal module called ` remoteip_module ` adding the following to httpd.conf fixed the problem. RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy 127.0.0.0/24